# Liquibase disable columnOrder diff

Tags: diff, liquibase

How can I disable the columnOrder from liquibase diff report? I looked into Liquibase source code and I can see diffColumnOrder property in the GlobalConfigurations file but I am not sure how to set this value when running the diff report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any of these kinds of configuration properties can be set in one of several ways, some of which depend on how you are running liquibase.

One way is to set a system property - so if you are using the liquibase.bat/liquibase shell script from the command line, you can add `-Dliquibase.diffColumnOrder=false` to the command line.

You could also set the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to have that property set.

A second way is to include the property name and value in a liquibase.properties file. In that case you can leave off the liquibase prefix - so your liquibase.properties file might look like this:

```
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.7:1521/orcl
username: someuser
password: somepassword
classpath: drivers/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar
diffColumnOrder: false
```

If you are running liquibase with maven, then you could do the same sort of thing by setting a property in the POM. If you are running liquibase programatically from your own code, you could set the property programatically.

Comment: I tried using both -D and also tried putting diffColumnOrder in liquibase.properties file. It did not work for me. When I put that property in liquibase.properties file it failed. I am on liquibase version 3.5.1 .

Comment: It appears that the flag wasn't added until liquibase 3.5.2:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/tag/liquibase-parent-3.5.2

The feature was added for jira ticket CORE-2800

Comment: I tried putting the flag in liquibase.properties in 3.5.3. It did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is then. I would probably run it in a debugger and see what it is doing.

Comment: I used  -Dliquibase.diffColumnOrder=false  and that worked. Thanks for your help.